# Python Logging in Multiple Scrapy Spider. Log File getting Corrupted

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, scrapy

I have a set of Scrapy Spiders, all configured to use the same log file and its configuration (using RotatingFileHandler).
The spiders are invoked from the Java program by calling it as an External Process.

Any spider may be invoked any time by the Java program, sometimes simultaneously or together depending on its task.

Since any spider may access the log file at any given time , the log files are corrupted. I do not mind the scrambling of logs so much, as the logs are formatted to include the thread id as well. But if a rollover is needed, the files get rolled over multiple times which results in erroneous naming/ordering of log files and sometimes deletion of intervening log files.

e.g if for e.g:
This is my rotatingFileHandler

```
RotatingFileHandler(filename=LOG_FILE_NAME,maxBytes=5*1024*1024,backupCount=10)
```

When the log file reaches size 5 MB, sometimes the log file gets rolled over twice. So the files will be Log, Log.3, Log.4 instead of Log, Log.1,Log.2.
In some cases, some of the log files are deleted and the others rolled over unexpectedly.

I can guess this maybe happening because of the multiple python instances  when each spider is running, leading to a race condition.

Is there any way I can stop this from happening? I have tried QueueHandler and QueueListener as well, but its not working. Maybe because each scrapy spider is running as a separate instance. Moreover the spiders are not running continously, but run only when called by the java program.

Python version is 2.7

Comment: You will probably have to make each process write to its own log file - make them unique by including e.g. the process pid in the filename, or something like that. You java program that is invoking the spiders could then concatenate the individual log file from the spider process that has just exited onto the main log - that way only one process is updating the main logfile.

Comment: Will this cause any major time penalty issues? The java program is time sensitive.

Comment: If there were an awful lot of spiders being created/dying quickly, I suppose it might, but that's impossible to answer from here. You will have to try it and see. Or you could make the spiders send complete log messages to a single file-writing service which then will write them to file in the order received.

Comment: @javaEd, I want to ask you another thing. It seems that scrapy didn't have the built-in RotatingFileHandler. Did you implement it by yourself?

Comment: I implemented it using the logging library of python. Created a configuration module using the same